# How to find and replace a substring in one cell with blank line in Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell with the following, `some text|, some text|, some text|` and I want it to appear as follows in another cell.

```
some text

some text

some text
```

I'd like the text to display in a single cell, but with a blank line between each (some text) at the "|" (pipe) character.

I've tried the this, `=SUBSTITUTE(D31,"|","&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&")`, but it puts the &CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)& as part of the string.

Any ideas or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=substitute(D31,"|,",char(10)&char(10))